# Which is better: Nginx compression or Apache Compression?

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, compression

I have an nginx reverse proxy in front of my apache server.

How should I configure compression (gzip or deflate) to serve my website? Should it be from nginx or from mod_deflate from apache? My primary concern is performance and memory usage.

Comment: http://www.pc-freak.net/blog/how-to-enable-output-compression-gzipfile-content-compression-in-nginx-webserver/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both represent [the same compression algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gzip) with a different format (gzip adds checksums). There is a similar question with a couple of good answers [here](http://www.w3support.net/index.php?db=so&id=388595).

There is a [web service testing compressed sites and showing the compression ratio](http://www.gidnetwork.com/tools/gzip-test.php) if you are interested in this kind of data. Although the data is not going to be comparable among different pages - the compression ratio depends on the properties of input data.

Edit: additionally, the compression level is configurable - Apache has the [DeflateCompressionLevel directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_deflate.html#deflatecompressionlevel) for configuring this.

Edit #2:  Nginx has the [gzip_comp_level directive](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpGzipModule#gzip_comp_level) for the same purpose (thanks Alaz)

And just in case it was not clear enough yet: given the same input data and the same compression level setting, you will see virtually the same compression ratio with both implementations (give or take a few bytes for the gzip checksums)

Comment: Nginx has `gzip_comp_level` to configure compression level as well.

Comment: My Q is on Nginx vs Apache.

Comment: ...he said they're both based on the same algorithm, just formatted differently. He pointed you to different comparison questions and sites as well for reference. I think his answer is basically telling you that nginx and apache are both doing the same thing underneath when it comes to compression, so it doesn't matter much; it depends on the compressibility of the content you're serving. If they had different compression engines it might be different.

Comment: Nginx seems to be a choice to make not based on compression, but for it's specific performance and features in certain circumstances. See http://www.linuxjournal.com/magazine/nginx-high-performance-web-server-and-reverse-proxy